# Is there a good entity to use for position manipulating in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to move around a camera in "free" with `/camera`,
and I don't know if there is a good entity to use to move around and set the camera's position to. This is for a freecam setup, so I need an entity that doesn’t fall. The best one I found in summon was a lead knot, but it can be destroyed by right-clicking. I thought NPCs wouldn't fall, but they do. if there is a better way to move a free camera around without set positions, that would help too.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an [Armor Stand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor_Stand#Bedrock_Edition)? It's the same height as a player, which could be helpful.

Comment: It falls, I need something that doesn't fall.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a floating armor stand? Put these in unconditional repeating command blocks with no delays.

```
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand] run tp @s @s
/tp @e[type=tripod_camera] @e[type=armor_stand]
```

This makes all armor stands float and teleports all cameras to the armor stand. You can still teleport the armor stand to you. **Do not use this with more than one armor stand**. If you must, use this:

```
/execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=camera] run tp @s @s
/tp @e[type=tripod_camera] @e[type=armor_stand,name=camera]
```

Comment: Im not using the education edition camera, I’m using the /camera command, but I think I can copy the second command from my forward backward left and right command blocks.

Comment: /camera doesn’t work like that, the command I’m using is:                                   /camera @p set minecraft:free pos ~ ~ ~ rot ~ ~